# SpringBoot Test JPA got "no session" exception when FetchType=Lazy

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit

I'm junit testing inside the below function:

```
    @Test
    public void testQueryUser(){
        User user1 = userRepository.findById(12L).orElse(null);
        assertThat(user1)
       .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("username", "adam");
    }
```

The below is my domain class User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @NotNull(groups = {Update.class})
    @Null(groups = {Create.class})
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID", hidden = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "user_role")
    @JoinTable(name = "sys_users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "dept_id")
    private Dept dept;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "sys_user_jobs",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "job_id")})
    private Set<Job> jobs;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true)
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "username")
    private String username;
}
```

Got the below error message **as expected**:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
> Expecting
> User(id=12, roles=[], dept=null, jobs=[], username=adam)
> to have a property or a field named "username" with value
> "adam"
> but value was:
> "paul"

But when switching `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` back to `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` inside domain class
I got

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role: com.adminsys.modules.system.domain.User.roles,
> could not initialize proxy - no Session

My questions are:

1. I'm only testing the field `username` but why JUnit is looking into field `roles`?
2. Why no session?
3. What's the best practice for my scenario?

Comment: You are testing data or more precies JPA. Use `@DataJpaTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`. It is more lightweight and has a driving transaction, which `@SpringBootTest` doesn't have, it you really want to stick with `@SpringBootTest` mark your test `@Transactional`, however I would strongly advice to use `@DataJpaTest`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, adding '@Transactional' annotation on top of the Test Method works!